# How to properly restore VBox VMs from backup?

Tags: virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, debian-wheezy

I just flattened and rebuild my home system recently, which had several VirtualBox VMs with snapshots. I backed-up all the VMs, VDIs and snapshots by copying the entire folder to an external drive. After the rebuild, I restored the folder to its original location, but when I open the VitualBox UI I get the error message:

[image]

Is there something I'm missing? Do I need to manually edit the .vbox files?

My host system is running Debian 7.4 and VBox 4.3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a search on your machine for a hidden VirtualBox directory `.VirtualBox`.

Remove this (or move it), then restart the software.

All should then be working.

Comment: The fix for me was to remove the `~/.VirtualBox` folder, restart the VBox client program, and then *Add* all the VMs manually via the *Machine* menu